# Programatically extract pattern from image file and / or PSD

Tags: php, css, xhtml, pattern-matching, photoshop

I often have to extract a pattern from a PSD to make an image to be used with XHTML and CSS.

I have often just made a guess in Photoshop, and then had to correct my *guesses* a few time after. It seems cumbersome.

Is there...

- Techniques for extracting a pattern from a Photoshop file with the selector tool?
- A Photoshop plugin perhaps that can do this
- Software that can parse a pattern image, and give me back the bare minimum to make a tiled pattern?

Should I just be requesting a copy of the pattern in addition to each PSD I receieve?

How have other people in my position tackled this problem before?

In matter of interest, how could / would I program something like this (I could use PHP with GD library)? Is it not worth my time? Would I loop through pixels left to right, and then identify image colours, and positions away from each other, and constantly check if new pixels are beginning to match an older pattern?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you having to identify within an image what portion repeats; or are you having to locate a suitable boundary that would create an appropriate tile without looking too obvious? It would seem programatically feasible in the first situation but decidedly more difficult in the latter.

Comment: @DanielRuf: Care to elaborate?

Comment: @alex meant imagemagick  for example see our project on github => https://github.com/KAOSFORGE/PSD-Library

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently working on a software that does this (and a couple more things to automate slicing of PSDs), but it's very slow even in C++. Right now i'm looking into GPU accelerated solution... 
So if there's an option for requesting pattern you should just do that.

Comment: I'm presuming that you finished this by now? :) Would you ever consider sharing it or a basic version of it on Github?